# Create Product Configurations Page Empty After Upgrade to 2.1.6

Tags: magento2

**Preconditions**

Magento 2.1.6 & PHP 7.0.18

**Steps to reproduce**

- Go to add new product in catalog
- Click on create configurations in the configurations section
- Page will show empty for the bottom half with the buttons showing up on
  the top

**Expected result**

First step is selecting the attribute value

**Actual result**

My screenshot of what I see

[image]

**Steps I have taken to try to fix this:**

- Ran setup:static-content:deploy
- Cleared and flushed cache
- Disabled cache

(No errors at all in the exception log or in the developer console)

Comment: Make sure you have PHP notice, warning and especially deprecated disabled. error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING); Have this in app/bootstrap.php. Check your php/web server logs too, to see the error.

Comment: @obscure If I change the bootstrap file for the error reporting then where would these errors show up when I visit the configuration section again?

Comment: @user3610374 : soon after you have un-comment ini_set('display_errors', 1); in bootstrap.php file and page loads, errors should display in the page itself.

Comment: @obscure This is what I have it set to but it doesn't seem to do anything

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: See in Google Chrome in Developer Toolbar, in Network tab > Xhr or > Doc tab. Magento 2 makes requests when you do actions (click buttons, submit forms, etc) .See which request is made and what returns. Sometime you can see the error in the request output. Also see  if there are JavaScript errors in console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cloudflare and apparently their rocketloader function doesn't work with this portion of magento and as soon as it was disabled, it showed up like normal